# Misclassification error in perceptron

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, classification, perceptron

I'm implementing a perceptron using Python and Numpy. I'm training it using the algorithm described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Learning_algorithm), but the resulting weights vector does not correctly classify sample vectors, not even the ones of the training set.

This training code I wrote:

```
epochs = 50
unit_step = lambda x: 0 if x < center else (0.5 if x == center else 1)

def train(data_set, labels):
    number_of_samples, dimension = data_set.shape

    # Generate the augmented data set, adding a column of '1's
    augmented_data_set = np.ones((number_of_samples, dimension + 1))
    augmented_data_set[:,:-1] = data_set

    w = 1e-6 * np.random.rand(dimension + 1)

    for _ in xrange(epochs):
        for sample, target in zip(augmented_data_set, labels):
            predicted_output = unit_step(np.dot(w, sample))
            update = (target - predicted_output) * sample
            w += update

    return w
```

After this I set as training set the necesary vectors to learn the AND logic function as:

```
training_set = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
```

and its corresponding class labels as:

```
labels = np.array([-1,-1,-1,1])
```

where -1 represent False and 1 represents True.

After running `w = train(training_set, labels)` I test the resulting weights vector and got this wrong results:

- `np.dot(w, [0,0,1]) = -1.0099996334232431`
- `np.dot(w, [0,1,1]) = -1.0099991616719257`
- `np.dot(w, [1,0,1]) = -1.009999277692496`
- `np.dot(w, [1,0,1]) = -1.009999277692496`

The error here is that the last case should return a value greater that 0 and close to 1. I can't see clearly what's happening here. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regardless of your code, a perceptron builds a statistical model based on the training input. Don't expect it to be 100% correct on the training data. In your case, I'd try increasing the number of epochs-- I've no idea how long it should take for a perceptron to converge on such a small training set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious error is lack of unification between training set labels (-1 and 1) and what your model outputs (0, 0.5 and 1.0). Change both to 0 and 1.